# Why is the same page screenshot not the same in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html2canvas

I have a code that take the screenshot of a div and send the canvas to a php code for storing in the server with jquery ajax.
I noticed that the screenshots is not the same even when the page content remains the same.

[image: first screenshot]

This is the first screenshot above which shows all the div content properly and below are the others that didn't

[image: second screenshot]

[image: third screenshot]

What could be the problem please?

The code is

```
function capture(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    var element = document.getElementById("report_card_page");
    html2canvas(element).then(function (canvas) {
     var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9);

     $.post("save-capture.php", {"image": image}, function(){
        alert("completed");
     });

  });

}
```

Edited:
This is the page where the div is located
[image]

Edited:
I noticed it works fine when I use dom-to-image to create the screenshot instead of html2canvas, it shows the full content but the screenshot produced is not sharp compared to html2canvas. Is there any solution to that, maybe I can use dom-to-image instead?

Comment: can you please highlight the difference in the image? or describe it

Comment: The bottom is cut partly

Comment: @Daenny use jspdf with html2canvas https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

Comment: or just use jspdf only, it lets you control image size in all the four sides

Comment: does it happen when you click it multiple times in one go or after reload ?

Comment: It happens both when I click on it multiple times and even after reload

Comment: I also noticed that it's like the table is compressed in the other 2 screenshot. Its obvious when you look at the "skills" table in the screenshot. The first is shown normally but not the other 2

Comment: so the problem is when you screenshot the page the first time it doesn't add the extra padding but after second try it adds it, and then after reload the same thing happens right? first okay and starts to add the padding on second/third tries, is that correct?

Comment: It does not have a particular order. Sometimes it just shows well and sometimes it doesn't. I tried generating several screenshot without reloading and some after reloading thinking there might be an order to it but there was none

Comment: can you show us a screenshot(manually) of your whole page on both scenarios?

Comment: Please what do you mean by manually? Do you mean the whole page where the div is located or the whole div section?

Comment: manually meaning without code just with some software, and i mean you browser tab not the specific div.. i'm trying to see if probably there is some content change that is adding the paddign

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: okay. are you changing any ui when the user triggers the screenshot function? also you might want to try this, remove the ``window.scrollTo(0, 0);`` since you can do that with ``html2canvas`` like ``html2canvas(element, {
        scrollX: 0,
        scrollY: 0
      })``, if it still doesn't work, then it might be hard to debug it without minimum reproducible code

Comment: I noticed it works fine when I use dom-to-image to create the screenshot instead of html2canvas, it shows the full content but the screenshot produced by dom-to-image is not sharp compared to html2canvas

Comment: `html2canvas` captures *what is rendered in the browser window*. The bottom is cut off because people using it have different sized windows and/or font sizes.

Comment: But all the screenshot I posted above are all done on the same device with the same browser and yet some show fully while the others don't. Even when I use the height and width property in html2canvas, it still doesn't work most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the solution is to put the report card on a different page. Nothing is on the page except the report card and the publish button. No sidebar or header or footer is there.