# why is html2canvas used in a loop not getting all the images in the div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html2canvas

I have a page with multiple report cards in separate div tags, each with a unique id. Each report card has a student picture and a school logo there. I also have another page that shows only one report card at a time.

I noticed that when I use html2canvas to convert the page with a single report card, it converts to an image fine, both the logo and student image shows on it but on the page with multiple report cards, when I try using a loop to convert about 8 report cards at once, some of the report cards logo and student picture does not show. They all got converted successfully to an image but the student picture and logo do not show in some. Other information in the report card showed fine.

What can cause this? below is the code I used to convert the page

```
                           function doCapture(report_id, loop_num) {

                                window.scrollTo(0, 0);

                                $.toast().reset('all');
                                showToast("<b>Please Wait</b>", "Processing your request...", "info", "#46c35f");

                                html2canvas(document.getElementById("report_card_page" + loop_num), {scrollY: -window.scrollY}).then(function (canvas) {

                                    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9);

                                    $.post("../worker/edit-report-card/save-all-capture.php", {"image": image, "report_id" : report_id, "loop_num" : loop_num}, function(data){
                                        $.toast().reset('all');
                                        if(data.includes(" :: ") == true){
                                            var toast_array = data.split(" :: ");
                                            if(toast_array[2].trim() != "success") showToast(toast_array[0], toast_array[1], toast_array[2], toast_array[3]);
                                            else { var total_loop_num = <?php echo $loop_stud_num ?>; if(loop_num == total_loop_num) alert("Publish Completed"); }
                                            //else { var total_loop_num = <?php echo $loop_stud_num ?>; if(loop_num == total_loop_num) showToast(toast_array[0], toast_array[1], toast_array[2], toast_array[3]); }

                                        }
                                        else{
                                            alert(data);
                                        }
                                    });

                                });

                            }
```

and the code to run the loop

```
                            $(".convert-multiple-result").click(function(){
                                var loop_num = <?php echo $loop_stud_num ?>;
                                for(let g = 1; g <= loop_num; g++){
                                    var report_id = $(".report_card_id" + g).attr("id");
                                    doCapture(report_id, g);
                                }

                            });
```

Each report card goes to a php file that saves the image in a folder. The only issue is that when i try to run the html2canvas in a loop, it does not show the student image or report card in some report cards. I forgot to mention that the report card content is a bit long.

Thanks.

Comment: To view how the report card looks like, follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136402/why-is-the-same-page-screenshot-not-the-same-in-html2canvas/69091830#69091830 the only difference is that there is a student image on the right side.

Comment: Please investigate in your Console to ensure that `report_id` has the correct value and exists in your HTML. Please also provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I was using `<img src="worker/open-image?name=<?php echo $school_image ?>&f=l" alt="logo">` to open the the image in the browser, the location of the image is in the open-image.php file. For some unknown reason, it was causing some images not to show sometimes and show some other time. I fixed it by using the location of the image directly in the img tag. e.g
`<img src="../../logos/<?php echo $school_image ?>" alt="logo">`